# How to embed a form inside a userform in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to embed a form inside a userform in MS Excel VBA? I need to create an embedded form with minimize, maximize and close window features in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually called a MDI (Multiple Document Interface) which has a parent form and a child form(s). VBA allows you to only create SDI (Single Document Interface). Though I am not sure about Microsoft Visio. But for the rest, it is definitely SDI

So the answer is "No". You cannot create MDI applications in VBA.